# MacOS X 10.5.8 on MacBook Pro

Tags: macos

Can you please tell me if MacOS X 10.5.8 on MacBook Pro a 32 bit environment or a 64 bit environment?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mac OS X 10.5 has a 32 bit kernel but is capable of natively supporting both 32 bit and 64 bit user space programs.

**Edit**

By the way, the original MacBook Pros only had a 32 bit processor.  If it is one of these, you are 32 bit only.

Comment: There's also a 64bit kernel, but it needs to be activated manually.

Comment: @Daniel: I know there are two kernels for 10.6, but I thought the 10.5 kernel was 32 bit only.

Comment: 10.5. True. That's 32 bit. Sorry about that.